# Check if value is in array then do

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have the following data:

[image]

The problem I'm trying to solve is that sometimes the `Column H (Place) and Column I (Country) switch places (ex: lines 9,10,11)`. What I would like to do is:

1. First check if the year is within the last 3 years (I don't need to fix data older than that).
2. Load a range of values into an array.
3. Compare if the values in Column H are in the array.
4. If not, then switch values between columns. I did that by simply copying and pasting.

I'm stuck at this point. Sorry if it's ugly, first time dealing with arrays

The list I load into the array is in one workbook and the data is on another workbook. Does it work or they need to be on the same workbook?

```
Sub check_data()
        Sheets("list").Activate 'this workbook

Dim DirArray As Variant

DirArray = Range("a1:a18").Value 'loads the range into an array

mypath = "//mynetworkpath/" 'sets the path

file = Dir(mypath & "filename.csv") 'indicates name of the file

Workbooks.Open (mypath & file) 'opens the file

Dim lastrow As Long

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 'sorting by year

Range("A2:K" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("B2:B" & lastrow), _
   order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

 end_year = Format(Now, "yyyy") - 3 ' last 3 years

x = 2 'starts from second row

Do Until Cells(x, 2) = end_year  'cells(row,col)

For y = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)

    If Sheet1.Cells(x, 8) = DirArray(y) Then

    Range("H" & x).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("M" & x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("I" & x).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("H" & x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("M" & x).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Range("I" & x).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

        Exit For
    End If

Next
   x = x + 1

 Loop

  ActiveWorkbook.Save

 ActiveWorkbook.Close True


End Sub
```

Any guidance is helpful!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leave the list on the worksheet and use match to check the values:

```
Sub check_data()

    Const FPATH As String = "\\mynetworkpath\" 'use Const for fixed values

    Dim rngVals As Range, wb As Workbook, lastrow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, tmp, file

    Set rngVals = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("list").Range("a1:a18") 'your lookup list

    file = Dir(FPATH & "filename.csv")

    If Len(file) > 0 Then

        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FPATH & file) 'opens the file
        Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

        lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        ws.Range("A2:K" & lastrow).Sort key1:=ws.Range("B2:B" & lastrow), _
                  order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo

        end_year = Year(Now) - 3 ' last 3 years

        x = 2 'starts from second row
        Do Until Cells(x, 2) = end_year  'cells(row,col)
            tmp = ws.Cells(x, 8).Value
            'use Match to check the value against the list
            m = Application.Match(tmp, rngVals, 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'got a match, so swap the values from H and I
                ws.Cells(x, 8).Value = ws.Cells(x, 9).Value
                ws.Cells(x, 9).Value = tmp
            End If
            x = x + 1
        Loop

        wb.Save
        wb.Close
    End If 'got the file

End Sub
```

Comment: This is a fantastic solution! I feel like I was complicating too much.The code should actually if it finds a match, do nothing, if it doesn't, than swap.  I just modified the part "If Not IsError(m) Then" to "If IsError(m) Then". It's working perfectly. Thank you.